# Kotlin: Higher order functions, how to add functions to a set and call them

Tags: function, lambda, kotlin, set, higher-order-functions

I have a class that holds a set of functions ("listeners") that are supposed to get invoked on a certain event (Gps update on Android, but that shouldn't be important here).
It looks like this (vastly simplified for clarity):

```
class myClass {
private var listeners = mutableSetOf<(Location) -> Unit>()

fun addListener(listener: (Location) -> Unit) {
    listeners.add { listener }
}

private fun updateListeners(location: Location) {
    if (!listeners.isEmpty()) {
        listeners.forEach {
            it.invoke(location)
        }
    }
}
```

Now I'm trying to add a function to my set from another class that I want to get invoked when updateListeners() is called.

```
class myOtherClass {

private fun registerLocationListener() {
    myClass.addListener (this::onLocationUpdateReceived)
}

private fun onLocationUpdateReceived(location: Location) {
    // do something with the location data
}
```

The compiler gives me no warning here, so I first assumed this is right. But onLocationUpdateReceived does not get called. If I log the items in my set with .toString(), I get

```
Function1<android.location.Location, kotlin.Unit>
```

which seems to be what I want - but I have limited experience with this matter, so I might be wrong. 
So I know that updateListeners() gets called, I know that "something" is put into my set, but onLocationUpdateReceived never gets called.

Can anybody help me with how I have to set this up so it works?

Comment: `listeners.add { listener }` adds lambda (new function) instead of your passed argument. Change this to `listeners.add(listener)` and see if it works.
Edit. late with response :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is the bug in the code

```
fun addListener(listener: (Location) -> Unit) {
    listeners.add { listener }
}
```

Here you `add` a new lambda to the `listeners` collection. The lambda does nothing, as you do not invoke the `listener`.
The right code is

```
fun addListener(listener: (Location) -> Unit) {
    listeners.add(listener)
}
```

Or you may say `add { listener() }`, but I see no reason for that

Comment: oh, those brackets - not the first time they got me. It's a little hard to find if you put these wrong...many thanks for pointing out the mistake!